Can't connect clickhouse to superset v4
I want to connect clickhouse DB to Apache Superset v4.0.0
I managed to connect my db to Superset v2.0, but now I need v4.0.0
I am trying to use sqlalchemy URI: clickhousedb://user:password@myhost:8123
And get this error:
ERROR: (builtins.NoneType) None
[SQL: Error HTTPConnectionPool(host='myhost', port=8123): Max retries exceeded with url: /?wait_end_of_query=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')) executing HTTP request attempt 1 (http://myhost:8123)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)

I already have installed the clickhouse-connect driver.

You probably can list the source that you referenced, so more information can be collected.

Name or service not known I suspect the host name
myhost is not able to be resolved in your client environment.
